# Utopia of children brought up by robots

Tags: robots, story-identification

I am looking for the title of a science-fiction book describing a colony (utopia) on another planet that has been established as a social experiment. The inhabitants had been brought up only by robots and therefore work perfectly as a society. I think there is no formal government and people work on what they are interested. If any catastrophe happens, they are able to form groups of specialists who react to the threat.
Later there comes a group of outsiders who decide to join and live in the utopia.
I am not sure, but author was probably Canadian.

Comment: Not sure, but there was a Futurama episode where Bender adopts a bunch of kids...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I wonder if you are remembering [*Voyage From Yesteryear*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyage_from_Yesteryear) by [James P. Hogan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_P._Hogan_(writer))?

Children raised by robots on another planet? **Check!**

Children grow to create an '[adhocratic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adhocracy)' utopia? **Check!**

A generation later outsiders from the originating culture arrive and try to join the colony? **Check!**

Canadian author? **Nope!** British-American.