# Colony of kids raised by robots surpasses earth society

Tags: story-identification, books

Read a science fiction story in 60s-70s. Involved a planet colonized by humans brought there as embryos and raised by robots. They loose contact with earth that is militarized and sends US ship ship and China ship to recontact the lost colony and bring them into the fold.

Colonists have society without money where people do what they enjoy, and leadership is something earned by respect of others due to performance. The colonists co-opt the crew by offering a better way to life.

When military leaders on ship decide to take colony by force it is discovered the colonists have a super weapon that could easily destroy ship. They had tested on their moon before ship arrived blasting a large crater.

Does anyone recall this story, title author, possible reprint? Thanks

Comment: Possible dupe of [Utopia of children brought up by robots](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/68225/utopia-of-children-brought-up-by-robots)?

Answer (score 5):

You seem to be describing [Voyage from Yesteryear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyage_from_Yesteryear) by James P. Hogan, as previously described in [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/68225/utopia-of-children-brought-up-by-robots)

> The team, led by Henry B. Congreve, change their mission priority and quickly modify the design to carry several hundred sets of electronically coded human genetic data. Also included in this mission of embryo space colonization is a databank of human knowledge, robots to convert the data into genetic material, care for the children and construct habitats when the destination is reached and a number of artificial wombs. The probe's designers name it the Kuan-Yin after the bodhisattva of childbirth and compassion.
>
> Shortly after the launch, global war indeed breaks out and several decades later, Earthbound humanity is united under an authoritarian government. It is this government that receives a radio message from the fledgling "Chironian" civilization revealing that the probe found a habitable planet (Chiron) and that the first generation of children have been raised successfully.
>
> As the surviving power blocs of Earth before the conflict are still evident, North America, Europe and Asia each send a generation ship to Alpha Centauri to take control of the colony. By the time that the first generation ship (the American Mayflower II) arrives after 20 years, Chironian society is in its fifth generation